# $\int fd\mu<+\infty$ iff $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{2^n}\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)\geq\frac1{2^n}\})<+\infty.$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the next:

Let $(X,S)$ be a measurable space. Let $f$ be a $S-$measurable function non negative and bounded. Then $\int fd\mu<+\infty\iff\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)\geq\frac{1}{2^n}\})<+\infty.$

If $\int fd\mu<+\infty$ we have for $E_{n}=\{x\in X:f(x)\geq\frac{1}{2^n}\}$ that $$\frac{1}{2^n}\mu(E_n)\leq\int f\mathcal{X}_{E_n}d\mu,$$ so
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\mu(E_n)\leq\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int f\mathcal{X}_{E_n}d\mu.$$

Also, there is a disjoint sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset S$ such that $A_n\subset E_n,$ and $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=0}^{k}A_{n}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=0}^{k}E_{n}$ $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}.$

In consequence $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int f\mathcal{X}_{E_n}d\mu=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int f\mathcal{X}_{A_n}d\mu=\int fd\mu.$$

My problem comes from the other direction. I was trying to express $E_n$ as a disjoint union of sets $\{x\in X:2^{m-n}\leq f(x)<2^{m+1-n} \}$ but I don't get any useful.

Any kind of help is thanked in advance.

Comment: By the hypotheses $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}2^n\mu(F_n)<\infty$, where $F_n=\{f(x)\ge 2^n\}$, hence $\int f\,d\mu=\sum_n \int_{F_{n}\setminus F_{n+1}}f\,d\mu\le \sum_n 2^{n+1}\mu(F_{n}\setminus F_{n+1})\le \sum_n 2^{n+1}\mu(F_n)<\infty$. :)

Comment: Dear @Squird37, I'm curious about your identity $\sum_{n\ge 0}\int f\chi_{E_n}\,d\mu = \sum_{n\ge 0}\int f\chi_{A_n}\,d\mu$, I think it is not right.

Comment: Thanks to answer @user90189. You're right. I was thinking that $\sum_{n=0}^{k}\int f\mathcal{X}_{A_n}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\int f\mathcal{X}_{E_n}$ but this is not true.

Comment: Thanks for your first comment. It was very helpful!! @user90189